# Strange underlines in font-awesome CSS

Tags: css, hover, font-awesome

When I hover on font-awesome's icons (when they're stacked together) like below (see picture). I get these strange underlines. Any idea where they could come from?[image]

Source:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <!-- FB -->
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=${shareURL}" target="_blank" style="color : #555">
    <i id="facebook" class="fa-3x fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
  </a>
  <!-- Twitter -->
  <a href="http://twitter.com/?status=Sign-Up+for+SolidTranslate+here!:+${shareURL}+@SolidTranslate" target="_blank" style="color : #555">
    <i id="twitter" class="fa-3x fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
  </a>
  <!-- LinkedIn -->
  <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=${shareURL}&title=Sign-Up%20for%20SolidTranslate%20here:%20${shareURL}&summary=To%20get%20started%20translating%20SolidWorks%20files%20register%2\
    0here:%20${shareURL}&source=${shareURL}"
    target="_blank" style="color : #555">
    <i id="linkedin" class="fa-3x fa fa-linkedin-square"></i>
  </a>
  <!-- Google+ -->
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=${shareURL}" target="_blank" style="color : #555">
    <i id="googleplus" class="fa-3x fa fa-google-plus-square"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: All of the current answers say basically the same thing, and none of them explain how I can keep the hover text-decoration of my container `a` tag while setting `text-decoration: none;` on just the font-awesome icon. I've tried all kinds of SCSS nesting, and I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Those lines usually come from the default (underline) `a` element style.

Either use another element or remove the underline :

```
a.social { /* or whatever your class */
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. See my answer for the true problem

Answer (score 9):

"text-decoration: none;" needs to be set with the ":hover" selector on the "a" tag, like this...

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Fontawesome** great and fun. But if you are using it as font, this is expected behaviour.

Add text-decoration to every state.
If you don't add `:link` it will show purple underline, very hard to see but it is there.
If you don't add `:active` it will show red underline when clicking, very visible.

```
a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited, a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `text-decoration` for `hover` effect on all `fa` class objects:

```
.fa:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `a` tags

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm shocked at all the wrong answers here. The lines are coming from your anchors, but only because you have extra white space between the `<i>` and `<a>` elements. Remove the space and the lines disappear.

E.g. make `</i>   </a>` into `</i></a>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="text-center">
  <!-- FB -->
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=${shareURL}" target="_blank" style="color : #555"><i id="facebook" class="fa-3x fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
  <!-- Twitter -->
  <a href="http://twitter.com/?status=Sign-Up+for+SolidTranslate+here!:+${shareURL}+@SolidTranslate" target="_blank" style="color : #555"><i id="twitter" class="fa-3x fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
  <!-- LinkedIn -->
  <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=${shareURL}&title=Sign-Up%20for%20SolidTranslate%20here:%20${shareURL}&summary=To%20get%20started%20translating%20SolidWorks%20files%20register%2\
    0here:%20${shareURL}&source=${shareURL}" target="_blank" style="color : #555">
    <i id="linkedin" class="fa-3x fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
  <!-- Google+ -->
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=${shareURL}" target="_blank" style="color : #555">
    <i id="googleplus" class="fa-3x fa fa-google-plus-square"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may also be necessary to use the important keyword in your class definition

```
    text-decoration: none !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the exact same problem, and it turned out that what was causing mine was a background change on hover effect I had set to my  container. I just had to change the  selector to a class selector and everything was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with such a weird problem also.
The problem was there was a border on the right and the bottom of the 'i' element.

[image: Ref]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your answer and replace the images with [code block]s.