# Some kind of underscore appears in Font Awesome icons in HTML

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, bootstrap-5

I am developing the Footer of a page in HTML using Bootstrap 5.3.0 and it turns out that when I add the icons, a kind of underscore appears next to them, I suppose it has to do with the white spaces between these elements, but a white space should not appear as such, but rather a transparent margin that does not allow the contact of the icons.

```
<footer class="text-center text-lg-start text-white" style="background-color: #1c2331">
    <section class="d-flex justify-content-between p-4" style="background-color: #6351ce">
        <div class="me-5">
            <span>Get connected with us on social networks:</span>
        </div>
                
        <div>
            <a href="" class="text-white me-3"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="text-white me-3"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="text-white me-3"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="text-white me-3"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
        </div>
    </section>
</footer>
```

[image: added picture]

Obviously, I tried to delete the collision boxes, and the underscore disappeared, but the separation between the elements also disappeared, also I tried to change the icons in case it was their problem, but it was not like that.

I want it to have the separation that I have right now, but the underscore at the end of the icons disappears because it doesn't look acceptable.

Comment: You can use 'text-decoration-none' bootstrap class. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/text/#text-decoration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
footer a {text-decoration: none;}
```